# xsl template to apply on required elements

Tags: xslt

there are few answers for this query but not able to achieve it what I wanted.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<Data>
<Lookup Name="InterchangeControlVersion">2</Lookup>
<Lookup Name="InterchangeReceiverID">whsmith</Lookup>
<Lookup Name="InterchangeReceiverQual">zzz</Lookup>
<Lookup Name="InterchangeSenderID">blackstone</Lookup>
<Lookup Name="InterchangeSenderQual">zz</Lookup>
<Lookup Name="Standard">bookexchange</Lookup>
<Properties Name="TPName1">abc</Properties>
<Properties Name="TPName2">ABC</Properties>
<Properties Name="TPName3">ApPlE</Properties>
</Data>

<book category="cooking">
  <extrainfo>
    <details1>best</details1>
    <details2>cakebake</details2>
  </extrainfo>
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

<publisher>
  <name>McBeth</name>
  <add1>Per Bothner</add1>
  <add2>paris</add2>
  <company>
    <vat>no</vat>
    <reg>SSaf1123</reg>
  </company>
</publisher>

<publisher-group1>
  <name>McBeth</name>
  <add1>Per Bothner</add1>
  <add2>paris</add2>
  <company>
    <vat>no</vat>
    <reg>SSaf1123</reg>
  </company>
</publisher-group1>

</bookstore>
```

I want to convert the value to upper case only from element book, I do not want any conversion on Data segment.
I want my output as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
   <Data>
      <Lookup Name="InterchangeControlVersion">2</Lookup>
      <Lookup Name="InterchangeReceiverID">whsmith</Lookup>
      <Lookup Name="InterchangeReceiverQual">zzz</Lookup>
      <Lookup Name="InterchangeSenderID">blackstone</Lookup>
      <Lookup Name="InterchangeSenderQual">zz</Lookup>
      <Lookup Name="Standard">bookexchange</Lookup>
   </Data>
   <book category="cooking">
      <title lang="en">EVERYDAY ITALIAN</title>
      <author>GIADA DE LAURENTIIS</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
   </book>
   <book category="children">
      <title lang="en">HARRY POTTER</title>
      <author>J K. ROWLING</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>29.99</price>
   </book>
   <book category="web">
      <title lang="en">XQUERY KICK START</title>
      <author>JAMES MCGOVERN</author>
      <author>PER BOTHNER</author>
      <author>KURT CAGLE</author>
      <author>JAMES LINN</author>
      <author>VAIDYANATHAN NAGARAJAN</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>49.99</price>
   </book>
   <book category="web">
      <title lang="en">LEARNING XML</title>
      <author>ERIK T. RAY</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>39.95</price>
   </book>
</bookstore>
```

I am currently using the below xsl but this is converting for every value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:variable name="smallCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

    <!-- Match document -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Deep copy template -->
    <xsl:template match="*|text()|@*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|text()|@*" mode="copy">
        <xsl:message>123</xsl:message>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="uppercase" select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Deep copy uppercase -->
    <xsl:template match="*|@*" mode="uppercase">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="uppercase" select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="uppercase"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="uppercase">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $smallCase, $upperCase)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="lowerCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
<xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title | author">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $lowerCase, $upperCase)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> I want to apply my uppercase template to all segments like Book and if
>   there are more except "Data"

Then do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="lowerCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
<xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[not(ancestor::Data)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $lowerCase, $upperCase)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this is working fine. For some reason this is not working in my oracle tool, let me do more research on it why it is not working in oracle soa.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't need to be so complex. You need only the identity template plus one matching `book/*/text()`, as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:variable name="smallCase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upperCase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book/*/text()"><xsl:value-of select="translate(., $smallCase, $upperCase)"/></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Jim / Michael.

Comment: Hi Jim, this is a sample xml, in my actual XML which is edifact xml I may have different segments like book. Actual match I want is to avoid the  segment "Data"  and attribute inside it like lookup or some more. I want to apply my uppercase template to all segments like Book and if there are more except "Data", Please advice. Thanks Sree

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for the solution, it is working fine, actually in my oracle soa, I had to add the namespace to my xsl stylesheet and it worked. Please let me know if I need to do anything to close this thread as answered?